# How do I switch between pages(Stages) which are in different classes through hyperlink?[JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, hyperlink

I would like to switch to other pages where the pages are located in different classes. I am doing in different classes so the code looks cleaner and simpler than mashing everything up in one classes. Here's the code that supposed to link with MainMenu page(class) in my Registration page(class):

```
home.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent action){
                frame.close();

        }
    });
```

and here's another page(class) which is the MainMenu that links to the Registration class:

```
    login.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent action){
            frame.close();
    });
```

> where "login" and "home" variables are hyperlinks.

My problem is that I want to connect between these two pages such that when I click the hyperlink, it goes to the directed class(page). I've tried calling the class name but nothing happened. I used the Class.launch(Class.class) thing but that is not the right way as far as I see.
Could anyone suggest how do I link this two pages?

Comment: There is really no difference between a Hyperlink and a Button. It's only a visual difference. So take the exact same approach you would if you were using buttons to change the stage.

Comment: I know. I just want to switch between stages in different classes. Hyperlinks or buttons aren't the issue

Comment: You need to post  minimal, and complete code that duplicates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use BorderPane, you can set your clicked page as center view:

```
    BorderPane appView = new BorderPane();
    YourPage page = new YourPage();
    appView.setLeft(null);
    appView.setRight(null);
    appView.setTop(null);
    appView.setCenter(page);
    appView.setBottom(null);
    page.asNode().requestFocus();
```

If your pages have separated Stages, you can hide current Stage and show your clicked Stage.